# How do I connect one computer to two networks

Tags: networking, dns

I need to access the internet and a completely separate private network from a single Windows 7 computer.  Each network is connected to my computer with its own network interface card.

The private network uses the '10.0.0.0' address space and provides its own DNS services.  This network is not connected to the Internet and I do not want to connect it to the Internet in a way, other than being able to access both from my computer.

Basic routing is not that big deal.  The problem is that no one wants to have to deal with IP addresses to get everywhere.

My default gateway points to the Internet and the default gateway is blank on the network interface for my private network.

My DNS server points to the Internet.

The show stopper at this point is figuring out a way to have my system use the DNS server on my private network for the DNS suffix used on my private network and still allow everything else to go out on the Internet.

Is there any way to make this work?

Bob

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the network interface card connected to the private LAN have you gone into the TCP properties and set a search domain and DNS server under the DNS tab? If you only need to hit a few hosts on the private LAN host file entries are also an option.